# Nginx で直リンク拒否ドメインを指定

Tags: nginx

画像の直リンクをNginx で拒否したいと思います。valid_refererを使った自ドメイン以外のリファラーを拒否する方法のチュートリアルは結構ありますが、指定ドメインで直リンクを拒否する方法がわかりません。invalid_refererというもので同様のことができるのでしょうか。

```
location ~ .(gif|png|jpe?g)$ {
     invalid_referer none blocked ~*badsite.com;
     if ($invalid_referer) {
        return   403;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`$invalid_referer` 変数は `valid_referers` ディレクティブによって設定されるもののようですが、私は `valid_referers` ディレクティブで否定の正規表現がうまく設定できませんで、代替案としてこんな感じで `map` を使って実装できそうですがいかがでしょう？

```
map $http_referer $block_by_referer {
    ~^https?://bad.example.com/ 1;
    default 0;
}
...
location ~ \.(gif|png|jpe?g)$ {
    if ($block_by_referer) {
        return 403;
    }
}
```